# Javascript Top-level conditional await problem: dependency page not loading

Tags: javascript

I made a helper function, getDefault(key, fallbackValue), that lets me get default values for components for testing purposes, that way I can supply some useful testable data when in development mode; in production mode we don't need this data so we default to the fallbackValue. Since we don't want to import this data file in production mode, I have a conditional if statement that only imports the data file when env_mode does NOT equal "production".

```
let getDefault;

if (env_mode === "production") {
    // This doesn't work unless I uncomment the following dummy await code!
    // await Promise.resolve();
    getDefault = (key, fallback) => {
        return fallback;
    };
} else {
    const data = await import("./test-data/data");
    getDefault = (key, fallback) => {
        const defaultValue = data[key];
        return typeof defaultValue === "undefined" ? fallback : defaultValue;
    };
}

export { getDefault };

// consumer.tsx
import { getDefault } from "./utils";

export const MyView = ...

MyView.defaultProps = {
   appointments: getDefault("appointments", []),
};
```

When consuming this in development it works fine, but fails to run in production mode; my component doesn't render, nothing happens, blank page, no errors or warnings. When I uncomment the dummy await line then it works fine. Would someone please illuminate me as to what is going on behind the scenes that's causing this?

edit: I am using webpack as a bundler and have experiments.topLevelAwait set to true

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I updated my post to reflect that I do use webpack; is this a bug?

Comment: I don't know. It certainly looks like it *might* be a Webpack bug. I suggest making an even more narrow test case like `let data; if (location.search.includes("wait")) { await Promise.resolve(); data = "waited"; } else { data = "didn't wait"; } export { data };` and something that does `import { data } from "./the-module.js"; console.log(data);` (or similar). If that replicates the problem, you probably want to post it to their issues list. You can see how it would be a challenge to have the bundler correctly handle a module that may or may not result in a promise...

Comment: Since it's just the dev branch that needs to use top-level `await`, you **might** be able to work around this by reformulating that `else` not to use it: https://pastebin.com/tJKJvmjH But that depends on when `getDefault` is called. If it's called by the top-level code in modules that import it, it'll probably fail. But if not, it'll probably work just fine.

Comment: (Hmmm... Although I'm not sure Webpack supports reassigning exports like that, now I think about it. [It's valid in true JavaScript modules -- imports are live bindings -- but again: bundling is hard.] So you might need something [like this](https://pastebin.com/D6Mf4Y1w) instead. Neither of those is something I'd do in production code, but for the dev branch, it seems fine to me.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I ran your code, and by default empty page, nothing happens, no console log whatsoever (I even added an extra console log as a first line in the consumer)... it's as if the consumer doesn't even get parsed. As soon as I add a query string containing the word "wait" then it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like you have something you can take to the Webpack issues list. (It may well be something they're okay with being a limitation of the tool.) Did you try the alternatives I suggested?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't because of the race-condition, which is what the top-level await is supposed to solve. I'm just adding that dummy await for now until I can figure it out. Thanks for your help!